# About DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Please tell me what is doing and (-5) is why used

and Explain DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"); what is doing in asp.net

Comment: It gives you a `date = currentDate - 5 days` in format "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Comment: You could have tested it by yourself.

Comment: Welcome. Sorry but this is not a good way to ask a question on here. You could probably find the answer much more faster with 10 seconds Google search instead of asking here. MSDN documentation is pretty clear about what `AddDays` and `ToString` methods do. Please show more effort next time. As a plus, you can _always_ read [FAQ] and [ask] a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives you a date which is `currentDate - 5 days`. For example today is `25th May` and this expression will give you `20th May`.

And `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` is a format, where d-Days, m-Months, y-Years

For example:

```
25-05-2018
```

PS `MMM` should be `MM`. So:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

should be replaced with:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its give you the date five days ago in format 20-05-2018

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`
So it will subtract 5 days from today so say its 01/06/2018
The date now will be 01/01/2018 and the **ToString()** will format it:
"01-01-2018".
If you want to keep the hour you should do something like:

```
ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```